# Django - How to create a user-owned group when registering?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django. User registration form contains fields such as username, e-mail, password. I want the user to create their own group when registering. How do I add this field?

**forms.py**

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Kullanıcı Adı')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola Doğrulama', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        ]

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Parolalar eşleşmiyor!")
        return password2

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        lenghtw = len(User.objects.filter(email=email))
        if lenghtw > 0 :
            raise forms.ValidationError('Bu email adresine sahip bir kullanıcı zaten var.')
        return email
```

**views.py**

```
def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user.set_password(password)
        #user.is_staff = user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Üye Ol'})
```

Comment: Are you talking about permission groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot OP gave as a comment is more explicit than his/her question, which should be edited :-)

As a summary:

- thanks to a view + form, you want to create a new user and a new group (`Grup Name` field),
- when your user is created, you want your user to automatically belong to your new group.

A few issues I see in your approach:

- you are coding a form which already exists in Django (`UserCreationForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms`), with unnecessary checks (as for password validation: it has already been done by Django),
- your field `Grup name` is not in your form by the way, did you forget it?
- your user needs to be saved to database already, so it can have a `pk` and be added to a group.

We could also use signals to do so, but let's go with your own approach:

```py
# forms.py

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    new_group_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Grup Name')
    def clean_new_group_name(self):
         # if you need to check the name of the group name
         [...]
```

```py
# views.py

def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save() # <--- ! don't use commit=False here
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        new_group_name = form.cleaned_data['new_group_name']
        new_group, created = Group.objects.update_or_create(name=new_group_name)
        user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name=new_group_name)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Üye Ol'}
```

Could you try if that works for you?

Comment: I get this error:
`"<User: test>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Comment: This happens if you try to associate a `m2m` field to an object not saved into the database yet (this is what you do when you write `commit=false`, object is not saved yet). Make sure you have `user.save()`, before trying to add a the new group to user's groups!

Comment: I couldn't say exactly. I will not register the user in the group section. I will include in the group.

Comment: What do you mean, you only want the group, not the user?

Comment: I hope I can tell with this [screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/Y77KQxd/group.jpg)

Comment: @witcher I edited my answer, if you want to have a look on it!

Comment: @witcher I just updated my answer, definition of `password` was missing (but you could have figured it out by yourself ;-p )

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem was solved with your help.